# Horizontal Scroll in chart library - WilliamChart

Tags: android, charts, statistics

I am using WilliamChart library to show some statistics. The problem is that I cannot make it scrollable.

I found the following method, but it is not working:

```
setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

@pindleskin : I faced same issue when i used AndroidPLot Chart . Try this way in your xml . I hope it will helps you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="230dp" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/RLayout_chart_container"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="230dp" >

    ///// Add your Chart Here

     </RelativeLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Give your feedback please

Comment: Hi ntelliJ Amiya. Unfortunately your suggestion did not work. I tried adding just a HorizontalScrollView as well without any luck.

Comment: Hi ntelliJ Amiya. In the end I had to switch to another library. Thanks though.

Comment: @pindleskin No problem . I tried . Okay .Which library ?

Comment: @pindleskin which library? MPAndroidChart can scroll fine but I face troubles with a scaling.

Comment: In the end I had to go with MPAndroidChart.

Comment: @pindleskin okay .Move ahead . I tried my best level